# Overfitting followed by well-fitting with large number of epochs

Tags: neural-network, overfitting, epochs

A few months ago I found an article it was explaining that some experiments had shown some networks would start well-fitting after overfitting happened in higher epochs. e.g. overfitting starts at epoch 100 but validation accuracy increases again after epoch 10000.

I don't remember what it was exactly. I searched for it but I couldn't find it yet. I'm looking for that topic. I would appreciate for any hint.

Comment: Do you happen to mean [double descent](https://openai.com/blog/deep-double-descent/)?

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for this topic